# Infor syteline 8.3 ,How to remove mandatory indicator while adding tables to the IDO?

Tags: erp

I have a new table and IDO on which I am developing a form in infor syteline 8.3.  Many of the fields are showing as mandatory even though they are not.  Data Source\Required show False.  What do I need to do to remove the mandatory indicator? 
Thanks,
Grant

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the table columns should not have any not null constraint and uncheck the Required fields in the IDO Properties.